# import EventHubManagementClientOptionalParams return error

Tags: javascript, typescript, azure, azure-eventhub, azure-eventhub-client

Typescript.
I use     "@azure/arm-eventhub": "^3.2.0",
and want to

```
import { EventHubManagementClient, EventHubManagementClientOptionalParams } from @azure/arm-eventhub; 

return 'Module "@azure/arm-eventhub"
```

has no exported member 'EventHubManagementClientOptionalParams'.'**
[image]

but I checked the doc,
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/@azure/arm-eventhub/eventhubmanagementclient?view=azure-node-latest#@azure-arm-eventhub-eventhubmanagementclient-constructor
[image]
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/@azure/arm-eventhub/eventhubmanagementclientoptionalparams?view=azure-node-latest
[image]

the constructor of Eventhubmanagementclient has Eventhubmanagementclientoptionalparams
and Eventhubmanagementclientoptionalparams is from arm-eventhub.

I try to use them to config the TLS version 1.2 like this:

```
import { EventHubManagementClient, EventHubManagementClientOptionalParams } from '@azure/arm-eventhub';

 const clientOptions: EventHubManagementClientOptionalParams = {
    pipeline: {
      minimumTlsVersion: 'TLSv1_2'
    }
  };

  const client = new EventHubManagementClient(credentials as any, Config.ArmSubscribtionId, clientOptions);
```

Comment: What is the exact blocker here? @yoyo

Answer (score 0):

The doc page you referenced is for the latest version of `@azure/arm-eventhub`, which is at 5.1.0 currently.

v3.2.0 has been deprecated. It does have a different API, for example, the constructor looks like this (from https://www.npmjs.com/package/@azure/arm-eventhub/v/3.2.0?activeTab=code)

```
  constructor(credentials: msRest.ServiceClientCredentials, subscriptionId: string, options?: Models.EventHubManagementClientOptions) {
```